# Basic ExcelFile read not working

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have just downloaded Python3.5 and have been trying to do a simple task (open an Excel file and remove the first three rows and various columns from the file) for several hours now with no success.

The lastest issue is happening when I try to open the file.

This is the only code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.ExcelFile("January2016.xlsx")
```

I get the following error no matter what read option I use with pandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2847, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-25-503f922e97e7>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.ExcelFile("January2016.xlsx")
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 257, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 422, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 833, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 548, in own_process_stream
    self_do_row(elem)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 745, in do_row
    value = error_code_from_text[tvalue]
KeyError: None
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you try `pd.read_excel("January2016.xlsx")`?

Comment: @coldspeed 'pd.read_excel("January2016.xlsx")' returns the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use [`pd.ExcelFile.parse(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) or [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).  `pd.ExcelFile` isn't a method that parses excel files, you need the `parse` part, too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried both and they both return the same error as above

Comment: Does your file have merged cells or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is 3 years old. Anyway hope this might help someone.

I came across this recently. I think the problem is caused by **a image** in the file. When I run the code in windows environment it works well. But when I run the code in ubuntu environment it gives a Traceback error.